# C++ Code Error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')

Tags: c++, string, truncate

What's wrong in this code? I am getting an error:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string truncateSentence(string s, int k) {
        int count=0;
        for(char it : s){
            if(it == ' '){
                if(count<k){
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }        
            
        }
        return count;    
    }
};
```

```
Line 16: Char 16: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')
        return count;
```

Comment: Count is an integer and the function is declared to return a string. What's not clear about the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function declaration is `string truncateSentence(string s, int k)` which indicates you are returning a `string`, but then you have `return count` where `count` is an `int`.

Thus, the error.

So, you need to either:

- change the return type to `int`:

  `int truncateSentence(string s, int k)`
- convert the `int` value to a `string` in the `return` statement:

  `return to_string(count);`